# Maven does not copy resource files

Tags: maven

I have a maven web application project that follows the maven standard directory layout so I have my resource files placed in src/main/resources/.

As this follows the standard I was expecting maven to automatically add the resource files to /WEB-INF/classes of the web application during the build but no files are copied.

I have to add the following lines to the build section of the pom file to get maven to copy the files:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

My question is: is this supposed to be necessary?

I was wondering if any of the build section plugins I use could somehow interfere with the copying of the resources. Are there any plugins that are known to do this?

The build section of my pom file is here:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>${tests.to.include}</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>${tests.to.exclude}</exclude>
                </excludes>
             </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/ITSelenium*.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.12</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add extra source directories</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals><goal>add-source</goal></goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>${project.basedir}/generated/src/main/java</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>add extra test directories</id>
                    <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                    <goals><goal>add-test-source</goal></goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>${project.basedir}/generated/src/test/java</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>add integration test sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>${project.basedir}/src/it/java</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <warName>res</warName>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp</directory>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0.905</version>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Any help or information will be much appreciated.

Comment: Maven copies resources automatically. why do you need you configuration? and no, there are should be no conflicts

Comment: Thanks for replying. I don't know why I need the resource configuration but if I build the project without it the resource files are not copied.

Comment: have you tried to use `targetPath`in the `<resources>`?

Comment: Does your POM extend a parent POM? Are <resources> specified there? Or, is there a profile in this POM (or a parent) that defines <resources>? If there is a parent, does it specify the maven-resources-plugin at all?

Comment: @Dmitry Senkovich: As I understand it targetPath is used to divert from the standard and select another destination for the resources. My problem is that the resources do not get copied at all and they should be without any configuration as the directory layout follows the standard.

Comment: @user944849: Thanks for replying. No the POM does not extend a parent POM. Profiles defined in the POM do not define any resources.

Comment: Look at the log carefully (maybe add `-X` for a debug log) to see what plugins are running in what order and see which are manipulating the classes directory.

Comment: For some reason it works now. I have not changed anything in the build process so I have no idea as to why it suddenly works.